# Is it possible to access an object's properties multiple times without repeating the object name?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to access an object's properties multiple times without repeatedly typing the object name? For example:

```
Using myObject {
    .Name = "name";
    .Colour = "red";
    .Age = "99";
}
```

Rather than having to type out something like:

```
myObject.Name = "name";
myObject.Colour = "red";
myObject.Age = "99";
```

Comment: No, there's no shorthand syntax for this. VB.NET has it, but not C#.

Comment: Only during assignment: `new Foo { Prop1 = "a", Prop2 = "b", ... }`

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/11/why-doesn-t-c-have-vb-net-s-with-operator.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. VB.Net has a way, but not C#

EDIT:

It's worth pointing out, that there is an initialization shorthand that is somewhat similar

```
var object = new SomeObject {
    Property1 = "string",
    Property2 = 0,
    Property3 = true
}
```

This works only for initializations. Once an object is initialized, there's no shorthand to access properties.